# whats best way to create documents Archive of images in the database's?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, save-image

What is the best way to create an  Archive of image documents in the database ?

Given we have about 2-10 million records and each record includes 2-4 images and about 20 text fields , what is the best way for create this archive so that we have good speed and high security for data?

Also, what database is good for this project?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use the file system as Minor suggested.

One option is SQL Server FILESTREAM. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Use file system storage for archive image. You must save link in DB for the image file. And if you use a HTTP content you can use the cache proxy server such as Squid, Nginx, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More questions for you:

1. How dynamic is the data? Do you store it once and never change it or it gets frequently changed?
2. Do you need versioning for the documents or the latest version overwrites the previous and that's it.
3. Are the documents always edited using one application or they can be changed outside (ex: using Word)
4. Are the documents related to other "non-document" data (database rows) or is it the only thing that you need to store?

Comment: at once documents(scaned photo) are tow but  maybe will add 2-4 new docmuments to database and we need to version for the documents but other type of fileds will be change , we have 5-6 tables in databes that related with these documents rows

Answer (score 0):

File system won't offer any real security, so I would discount that straight off.

In Oracle there is built-in image support through the [ORDImage type](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14302/ch_intr.htm#sthref31).

Check out Marcel's [blog](http://eternal-donut.blogspot.com) as he, and the [Piction](http://www.piction.com/solutions/imagelibrary.html) company, do a lot of work in this area and he has lots of useful material to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use control downloads. Look at http://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/lang/en/